# Hazelcast Jet 0.6.1 + Pipeline API + Custom Processor

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I am trying to attach custom processor to the Hazelcast Jet Pipeline definition.

Here is sample code.

```
private Pipeline buildPipeline() {

   Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
    p.drawFrom(Sources.<String, Record>remoteMapJournal("record", 
   getClientConfig(), START_FROM_OLDEST))
      .addTimestamps((v) ->  getTimeStamp(v), 3000)
      .peek()
      .groupingKey((v) -> Tuple2.tuple2(getUserID(v),getTranType(v)))
      .window(WindowDefinition.sliding(SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH_MILLIS, 
      SLIDE_STEP_MILLIS))
      .aggregate(counting())
      .map((v)-> getMapKey(v))
      .customTransform("test2", ()-> this);

     return p;

    }
```

Here is sample code for tryProcess() method

```
    protected boolean tryProcess(int ordinal, Object item) {
    TimestampedEntry entry = (TimestampedEntry)item;
    System.out.println("Item value is "+ item);
    map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    return true;
}
```

On execution, I got the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: These transforms have nothing attached to them: [test2]
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.pipeline.Planner.validateNoLeakage(Planner.java:104)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.pipeline.Planner.createDag(Planner.java:65)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.impl.pipeline.PipelineImpl.toDag(PipelineImpl.java:85)
    at com.hazelcast.jet.JetInstance.newJob(JetInstance.java:94)
    at com.sap.banking.bc.AbstractAuditLogProcessor1.start(AbstractAuditLogProcessor1.java:132)
    at com.sap.banking.bc.JobProcessor.main(JobProcessor.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
```

Is anything missing ? Will you please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: You shouldn't use a custom transform for your case. You can just use a map sink.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that you miss a sink, a `drainTo` call.